# Who are the first 10 persons to enter Jahannam?

Tags: hadith, sahih-muslim

As-Salam,

Can anyone please tell me who are the first 10 persons to enter Jahannam?

Answer (score 1):

No one knows who were the 10 People who were in Hell ONLY Allah knows. Since IDK the answer to ur question I will make it up for u by telling u a story that my Uncle told me. Back in the Day there was a Female Muslim. This Female Muslim did literally all of the Good Deeds in Islam. The Female Muslim didn’t feed her Cat any Food causing the Cat to Starved. I honestly feel bad for the Cat Peace be upon the Cat. The Cat sadly passed away and the Cat & Allah communicated together. The Cat wanted the Female Muslim to go to Hell and she went to Hell. My Theory is that the Female Muslim went to Hell then go to Heaven idk but Allah knows.

Comment: Salaam @Amir .. Welcome to StackExchange. Please note that adding sources to your Daleel will make your answers more trustworthy for others. (https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3318) ... Best of luck and looking forward to more contribution form your end in the future inshallah

Answer (score 0):

I don't specifically know the first ten but I do know the first three.

They are not in the order either  ( I don't know who will go in first )

A man will be called before Allah. Allah will ask him :"What did you do with the wealth I gave you?" ; The man will reply : " I donated it all away for your cause ya Allah " ; Then the angels will say : "You are lying!" "You gave your money away to show off to others! " ; And he'll be thrown into the fire.

A man will be called before Allah. Allah will ask him "what did you do with the strength I gave you?" ; The man will reply "I fought for you you ! I fought to protect the Muslims! " ; The angels will say " You are lying ! " "You fought only to show off to the others! " ; And he'll be thrown into the Fire.

A man will be bought before Allah.  will ask him " What did you do with the Knowledge I gave you? " ; The man will reply " I taught it to others ! I spread your teachings! " ; The angels will say : "You are lying ! " " You taught only to show off to others! " ; And he will be thrown into the Fire.

Subhanallah

HellFire will be kindled with these 3 PEOPLE : 3 Men who were given Wealth, Health and Wisdom by Allah SWT. The other people saw them using these blessings for the good of others.

BUT

These people. ..There intention was not to serve ALLAH but - to SHOW OFF to OTHERS!

Sourced from MercifulServant : "The first three to enter hell"

Allah knows best

Comment: This post could use evidences to support your claims.

Comment: I have mentioned the evidence right  ? I got these facts from a YouTube Video of MercifulServant channel.

Comment: Youtube is not a source of knowledge.